# How do I make the items in a ListView a different color?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a ListView full of ListViewItems.

I want to emphasize some of them when a certain event fires, so I'm looking for a way to change the color of the listview to something other than black (red would be delightful).

Is it possible to dynamically change the color of the items in the default winforms ListView?

If no, is there some easy way to otherwise emphasize the items dynamically?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The color of a list view item is straight forward:

```
ListViewItem li = new ListViewItem();
li.ForeColor = Color.Red;
li.Text = "Sample";
listView1.Items.Add(li);
```

Changing the background color of the list view itself is just `listView1.BackColor = Colors.Red;`

Modifying an item in the ListView:

```
foreach(ListViewItem li in listView1)
{
   if(li.Text = "Sample")
   {
     li.ForeColor = Color.Green;
   }
}
```

Comment: I was unaware of the ForeColor property. Thank you!