# How can i color each item in another color in a listView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

First of all is this way of handling the listView adding items in the constructor is the right way ? And second how can i color all the text "Ready" in Red ? Only "Ready" ?

```
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.GridLines = true;
        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;

        //Add column header
        listView1.Columns.Add("Status", 70);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Country", 70);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Link", 399);

        string[] arr = new string[countriesCodes.Length];
        ListViewItem itm;
        for (int i = 0; i < countriesCodes.Length; i++)
        {
            arr[0] = "Ready";
            arr[1] = countriesCodes[i];
            arr[2] = lines[i];
            itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
            listView1.Items.Add(itm);
        }
```

Screenshot of the listview when running the prgoram:
I want to color only the Status column row in red i mean only to color the text "Ready" in red the rest not to color.

[image: All is in red]

If i'm adding this method:

```
private void colorReady()
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem li in listView1.Items)
            {
                if (li.Text == "Ready")
                {
                    li.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
        }
```

And then calling colorReady(); in the constructor after setting all the listView it will color all the items in the listView like it's showing in the screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make the items in a ListView a different color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400146/how-do-i-make-the-items-in-a-listview-a-different-color)

Comment: The *right* way for your case is the *wrong* way for another.  Impossible to determine what is right for you without any other information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a void and name it whatever, I named it `colorReady`.

```
    private void colorReady()
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem li in listView1.Items)
        {
            if(li.Text == "Ready")
            {
                li.SubItems.Add("Color");
                li.SubItems[0].ForeColor = Color.Red;
                li.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then call it after your code above.

```
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.GridLines = true;
        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;

        //Add column header
        listView1.Columns.Add("Status", 70);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Country", 70);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Link", 399);
        string[] countriesCodes = new string[] { "test1", "test2", "test3" };
        string[] arr = new string[countriesCodes.Length];
        ListViewItem itm;
        for (int i = 0; i < countriesCodes.Length; i++)
        {
            arr[0] = "Ready";
            arr[1] = countriesCodes[i];
            itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
            listView1.Items.Add(itm);
        }

        colorReady();
```

Add an item that is not 'Ready' to test the result.

Comment: I edited my question with a screenshot. It's coloring all the items not only "Ready"

Comment: Did you mean you only wanted the cell where 'Ready' is in, to be red and not the whole line? Or even the line that is not 'Ready' is also red.

Comment: Yes i mean only the cells under Status to be in red. Later i will want to change this cells text also for example from "Ready" to "Downloaded" but yes i mean all the cells that are under the column Status.