# C# ListView diffrent text for each row

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I want to change the text color in the ListView based on Item attributes but i didn't find the way to solve this problem.

Comment: If you posted the code you tried it would be easier to help you, but have you tried, If (someAttribute == something) listView.Items[index].ForeColor = Color.Red;?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make the items in a ListView a different color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400146/how-do-i-make-the-items-in-a-listview-a-different-color)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I just use `ListViewItem` and then set the color. Like in following code.

```
var item1 = new ListViewItem(new[] { t.Text, t.Date.ToString() });
item1.ForeColor = t.Color;
listTodos.Items.Add(item1);
```