# ListView specific item color

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I list site addresses with Android listview.I tried for hours, but I couldn't find a solution.

for example

`http://site .com`

`http://site2 .com`

`http://site3 .com`

`http://site4 .com`

if have `http://site3.com` in `listView` i want to change the color of this line.

```
 final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
        MainActivity.this, 
        resultsdatalist,
        R.layout.list_item, 
        new String[]{"resultid", "result"}, 
        new int[]{R.id.resultid, R.id.result}) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        return view;
    }
};


lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: you should use BaseAdapter instead of SimpleAdapter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make the items in a ListView a different color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400146/how-do-i-make-the-items-in-a-listview-a-different-color)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    if(getItem(position).equals("site3.com"))
        {
           // do something change color
           view.setBackgroundColor (Color.RED); // some color  
        }
        else
        {
           // default state
           view.setBackgroundColor (Color.WHITE); // default coloe
        }
        return view;
    }
```